# How can i add blank icon space to preferencefragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

When in a preferencefragment you can add an icon to appear to the left of the preference. However then the alignment for preferences without an icon is funky. How can i add a blank space to make all the preferences have the same alignment. I included a picture below.

I have tried adding

```
android:icon="@null"
```

to the preference however it did not work.

Results i am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hack, you can take white or same background icon in drawable.

Example:

```
<Preference
     android:title="Done"
     android:icon="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen

Comment: Like you can not add regular CheckBox, each component you want, has its preference class extending android Preference class. for checkbox it is CheckBoxPreference.

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: You can not add Space, that you can add in layout.xml

Comment: Here is a tutorial which you can read to understand Preference activity. Preference activities are used to make settings page of app. Like android mobile has.

Comment: What is the way you asking?

Comment: I want you try creating a preference activity You can not add <Space as direct child of PreferenceScreen.